# jQuery using Regex to find links within text but exclude if the link is in quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am using jQuery and Regex to search a text string for http or https and convert the string to a URL. I need the code to skip the string if it starts with a quote.

below is my code:

```
// Get the content
var str = jQuery(this).html();

// Set the regex string
var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;

var replaced_text = str.replace(exp, function(url) {
    clean_url = url.replace(/https?:\/\//gi,'');
    return '<a href="' + url + '">' + clean_url + '</a>';
})

jQuery(this).html(replaced_text);
```

Here is an example of my issue:

Text `The School of Computer Science and Informatics. She blogs at http://www.wordpress.com and can be found on Twitter <a href="https://twitter.com/abcdef">@Abcdef</a>.`

The current code successfully finds the text that starts with http or https and converts it to a URL but it also converts the twitter URL. I need to ignore the text if it starts with a quote or is within an a tag, etc...

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about adding `[^"']` to the `exp` variable?

```
var exp = /(\b[^"'](https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
```

Snippet:

```js
// Get the content
var str = jQuery("#text2replace").html();

// Set the regex string
var exp = /(\b[^"'](https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;

var replaced_text = str.replace(exp, function(url) {
    clean_url = url.replace(/https?:\/\//gi,'');
    return '<a href="' + url + '">' + clean_url + '</a>';
})

jQuery("#text2replace").html(replaced_text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="text2replace">
The School of Computer Science and Informatics. She blogs at http://www.wordpress.com and can be found on Twitter <a href="https://twitter.com/abcdef">@Abcdef</a>.
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you! @lpg

Comment: If a link is located at the start of the string, it won't get matched with the current regex.

Answer (score 0):

If you really just want to ignore the quotation marks, this could help:

```
var replaced_text = $("#selector").html().replace(/([^"])(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig, '$1<a href="$2">$2</a>');
```

Answer (score 0):

**This works for me:**

This will recognize urls and convert them to hyperlinks, but will ignore urls, wrapped in `"` (quotes).

See the code below or this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sxc0wued/66/) for a working example.

#### Example HTML:

```html
<ul class="js-replaceUrls">
    <li>
        www.link-only-www.com
    </li>
    <li>
        http://link-starts-with-HTTP.com
    </li>
    <li>
        https://www.link-starts-with-https-and-www.com
    </li>

    <a href="https://link-starts-with-https.com">
        Link in anchor tag
    </a>
</ul>
```

#### RegEX:

```
/(([a-z]+:\/\/)?(([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+([a-z]{2}|aero|arpa|biz|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|jobs|mil|museum|name|nato|net|org|pro|travel|local|internal))(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/[a-z0-9_\-\.~]+)*(\/([a-z0-9_\-\.]*)(\?[a-z0-9+_\-\.%=&amp;]*)?)?(#[a-zA-Z0-9!$&'()*+.=-_~:@/?]*)?)(\s+|$)/gmi
```

#### jQuery:

```
// RECOGNIZE URLS AND CONVERT THEM TO HYPERLINKS 
// Ignore if hyperlink is found in HTML attr, like "href"
$('.js-replaceUrls').each(function(){
  // GET THE CONTENT
  var str = $(this).html();

  // SET THE REGEX STRING
  var regex = /(([a-z]+:\/\/)?(([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+([a-z]{2}|aero|arpa|biz|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|jobs|mil|museum|name|nato|net|org|pro|travel|local|internal))(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/[a-z0-9_\-\.~]+)*(\/([a-z0-9_\-\.]*)(\?[a-z0-9+_\-\.%=&amp;]*)?)?(#[a-zA-Z0-9!$&'()*+.=-_~:@/?]*)?)(\s+|$)/gmi;
 
  // REPLACE PLAIN TEXT LINKS BY HYPERLINKS
  var replaced_text = str.replace(regex, "<a href='$1' class='js-link'>$1</a>");

  // ECHO LINK
  $(this).html(replaced_text);
});

// DEFINE URLS WITHOUT "http" OR "https"
var linkHasNoHttp = $(".js-link:not([href*=http],[href*=https])");
        
// ADD "http://" TO "href" 
$(linkHasNoHttp).each(function() {
  var linkHref = $(this).attr("href");  
  $(this).attr("href" , "http://" + linkHref);
});
```

See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sxc0wued/66/) for a working example.